# What is the best way to test WebdriverIO "browser" object?

Tags: webdriver-io

I started  using WebdriverIO and noticed that the `browser` object it provides has a ton of methods, so I would like to play with it without having to run things from CLI.

Is it even possible to do something like open the page I want to run tests against on my browser and somehow use that object from the browsers console to see the results of the methods?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible to use a browser object in the browser console because the object is the browser (driver) itself. Consider that object as a back-end interface that allows to do some actions on the browser itself. In terms of playing around, take a look at chimp.io

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to run JavaScript from within the browser, take a look at [the 'execute' command](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html).

There's also [a full page of docs on the browser object for reference](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/browserobject.html).